# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'langchain_experimental'

Tags: json, output, langchain, large-language-model, structured-data

I am trying to utilize LangChain's LLM (Language Model) with structured output in JSON format. During my attempt to import the necessary module, I encountered the following error:

```
from langchain_experimental.llms import JsonFormer

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'langchain_experimental'
```

Has anyone encountered a similar issue with importing JsonFormer from langchain_experimental?
Is there a specific step or additional installation required for the langchain_experimental module?
Are there alternative ways to achieve structured output in JSON format with LangChain's LLM?
Any assistance or insights on resolving this import error would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install langchain_experimental
```